# LinkedIn scraping using selenium (problem)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# ------------------- LinkedIn gobs link
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("LinkedIn_Gob_Link")

# ------------------- Login to LinkedIn
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Sign in').click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username').send_keys('My_Username')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password').send_keys('My_Password')
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'from__button--floating').click()

# ------------------- Get a_tag in job list and click it
jobs_titles_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.scaffold-layout__list-container .job-card-list__title--link')
for a_tag in jobs_titles_links:
    a_tag.click()
    print(a_tag.get_attribute('href'))


time.sleep(3000)
driver.quit()
```

I want to print a_tag but instead of printing the whole list it has like (23) jobs title links it prints only 7 is it the scrolling thing or else? how can I solve this?